# All Consumer group not receiving messages

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka Producer which is producing messages and couple of consumers(group) who are trying to consume them. I created a topic which has 3 partitions and started 2 consumers with `--group` parameter. The issue I am facing is that all the messages are being routed to a single consumer. Following are the commands which I ran to create the topic, start the producer and consumer.

To create the kafka topic

`kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic logs --partitions 3`

When the I describe the topic this is what I get

```
Topic: logs TopicId: BtXbA3igQPmx5qsURAhq7Q PartitionCount: 3   ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
    Topic: logs Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: logs Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: logs Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

Started the producer using the below command

`kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic logs`

and the both the consumers using this

`kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic logs --group my_group`

When I try to describe the group I am getting the following error.

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server locahost:9092 --describe --group my-group
[2022-10-23 14:21:07,711] WARN Couldn't resolve server locahost:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for locahost (org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:134)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.createAdminClient(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:696)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.<init>(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:176)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.run(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:67)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:59)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:505)
```

I am using Kafka version 3.3.1 and running on Mac OS. This is a fresh installation of Kafka and I have not made any changes in the config dirs. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While describing the group you have mis-spelled localhost as 'locahost'
Also, you have created a group "my_group" while during describing you have mis-spelled it again as "my-group"

Answer (score 1):

Probably all your messages go to the partitions assigned to only one of the consumers. If you run two consumers then one will have two partitions and another one partition assigned. Add the flag `--property print.partition=true` to the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` and look where the messages go.